# Create an exe-File in Maven with VM-Arguments for said exe

Tags: java, maven, exe, launch4j

i am currently working on a Java-Project that needs VM Arguments specifying the java.library.path. When running my program out of Eclipse - No problem, i can specify my VM arguments easily. Now i want to build my project via  maven and haven't found a possibility to give said arguments to this exe.

Just calling my exe with this argument on the command line does not work, so where do i have to put this information in my pom-file?

Comment: Which Maven plugin do you use the create the .exe file?

Comment: I'm using launch4j

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9519421/14955

Comment: Weirdly maven tells me that launch4j does not know the `<opt>` tag