# Calling an exe-File with JVM Arguments

Tags: java, jvm, exe

i am currently developing a java-Programm that is going to be deployed via an exe-File. The problem is that i have to specify the `java.library.path` when calling this exe.
I tried just calling the exe with the command line argument `-Djava.library.path=[...]` but since i also am using some different command line arguments this does not seem to work.

So to clarify my question: How do you call an exe-File with JVM arguments and/or create an exe File that already holds this information?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you produce that .exe file?

Comment: Via maven. The file itself is fine, it's just about that argument.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933950/create-an-exe-file-in-maven-with-vm-arguments-for-said-exe?rq=1

Comment: Did you find any way to pass the JVM arguments while running exe file?